# How do I add an index page to the GitLab bundled NGINX?

Tags: linux, nginx, centos, gitlab, centos7

I've recently installed GitLab, and I'm using the bundled NGINX with it. I've been able to successfully set it up, and put it on `mydomain.com/lab`

Great! Only problem is that when you go to `mydomain.com`, it has a 404 page. Well, duh. I need to upload my `index.html`... but WHERE do I do it?
How can I add my index page to the bundled NGINX? Most of all, WHERE do I upload it?

I'm using CentOS 7, and for the love of God I swear I've looked in every directory and I have no idea where to throw my index page in. Please bear with my ignorance as I'm quite new to this.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have install [GitLab under a relative url (subdomain)](http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/install/relative_url.html), using the [`relative_url_root`](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/fb5682e7cd587e7e6c871588240fc49b325b042f/config/gitlab.yml.example#L47) rule in `gitlab.yml`.

You can try in your [gitlab nginx config file](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/fb5682e7cd587e7e6c871588240fc49b325b042f/lib/support/nginx/gitlab#L40), to define a root and redirect the rest to another location, in which the gitlab reverse_proxy rules apply: see "[Getting Nginx to point to a specific `index.html`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25844348/6309)"

```
location / {
    root /custom path/for/index.html;
    error_page 404 = @gitlab;
    expires 30d;
}

location @gitlab {
    client_max_body_size 0;
    gzip off;

    ## https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/694
    ## Some requests take more than 30 seconds.
    proxy_read_timeout      300;
    proxy_connect_timeout   300;
    proxy_redirect          off;

    proxy_http_version 1.1;

    proxy_set_header    Host                $http_host;
    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto   $scheme;

    proxy_pass http://gitlab-workhorse;
}
```

Comment: I located the NGINX config file, but it says at the very top
# This file is managed by gitlab-ctl. Manual changes will be erased! To change the contents below, edit /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb and run `sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure`.

And obviously when I made the right changes they had no effect, so what do I edit in the gitlab.rb file so that I can edit the NGINX config? 

Thanks.

Comment: @MilesJefferson I agree, this is not a standard GitLab configuration, so I don't know if it is possible to do it, but I was trying to give at least one clue as to how it could work.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I'll see what I can do and get back to you on that.